# Apply simple operation on array with sublists of unequal length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list made out of two sub-lists of unequal length:

```
a = [[0.2, 0.3], [0.6, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8]]
```

I nee to divide all elements by 10, so I though I could just convert `a` to a `numpy` array and then apply the operation like so:

```
np.asarray(a) / 10.
```

but this results in:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'
```

I could do this:

```
np.asarray([np.asarray(a[0]), np.asarray(a[1])]) / 10.
```

but I'm pretty sure this isn't the pythonic way to do this.

What is the correct way to apply an operation on an array made out of sub-lists with different lengths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the looks of:

```
In [273]: [(np.array(i)/10).tolist() for i in a]
Out[273]: [[0.02, 0.03], [0.06, 0.05, 0.06999999999999999, 0.08]]
```

Simply converting `a` to array is not good because it leaves the elements (2 of them) as lists.

```
In [275]: np.array(a)
Out[275]: array([[0.2, 0.3], [0.6, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8]], dtype=object)
```

An array of `dtype=object` is little more than a list with an array wrapper.  So you need to convert the sublists to arrays if you want to use the array division.

But the pure list comprehension version looks even cleaner - and more pythonic:

```
In [279]: [[j/10. for j in i] for i in a]
Out[279]: [[0.02, 0.03], [0.06, 0.05, 0.06999999999999999, 0.08]]
```

In my book, list comprehensions are very 'pythonic'; nested ones even more so. :)   Unnecessary use of `numpy` is un-pythonic, especially if it requires `tolist` afterwards.

---

An array of `dtype=object` tries to apply the operation to each element, e.g.

```
np.array(a)/10 => np.array([i/10 for i in a])
```

It doesn't work in the sublist case because `[2,3]/10` is not defined.

But if we take the extra step of converting the sublists to array:

```
In [282]: aa=np.array([np.array(i) for i in a])

In [283]: aa/10.
Out[283]: array([array([ 0.02,  0.03]), array([ 0.06,  0.05,  0.07,  0.08])], dtype=object)
```

then the array division works.  But don't count on this working for all operations.  The `dtype=object` array code is not fully developed.

Comment: I'm selecting this answer because of it's simplicity, ie: it uses neither `numpy` nor the `lambda` function.

Answer (score 3):

Do you need `numpy`? Otherwise you can just use a simple list comprehension:

```
b = [map(lambda x:x/10, i) for i in a]
```

Comment: Not necessarily, I just default to `numpy` for all operations on arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this if you need to directly modify the existing list.

```
for i1, l in enumerate(a):
    for i2, _ in enumerate(l):
        a[i1][i2] /= 10
```